# How can we get the details of a SSL enabled webpage with Objective C for an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ssl, uiwebview, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have two requirements as follows.

1. I have a requirement in my iPhone App that the SSL certificate details of the https enabled webpage should be read and stored into my app. This could be done in background process or at the time of loading the webpage in UIWebView controller. Is it possible? If so, can you please provide the Objective-C code to get the details.
2. Is it possible to verify the Extended Validation(EV) certificate of a https enabled webpage? If so, please provide the Objective-C code for this.

Many thanks in advance.

Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer to 1 is that you cannot do it. There is no way to provision a SSL certificate to any keychain access list (other than the Apple one) other than including it in the bundle. See my related question:

[Finding a certificate on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378892/finding-a-certificate-on-ios)