# Distributing individual client certificates to iPhone

Tags: iphone, certificate

We are looking for a solution for distributing individual client certificates to an enterprise distributed app.
As far as I know it‘s not possible to access a certificate installed with Mail or Safari in your app (see for example here: [Finding a certificate on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378892/finding-a-certificate-on-ios)). So what we like to know are there any other ways to automatically distribute a certificate to individual users? Maybe there‘s a solution via iPhone Configuration Utility (e.g. setting certificate‘s access group)? Or may there‘s a way to add an individual certificate to app bundle before distributing it to the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute certificates (and keys) with IPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility), but that's a tedious and manual process.

If you want something automated you'll have to look into Mobile Device Managers and see which ones support distributing certificates. Oherwise I know [OpenTrust](http://www.opentrust.com/) has a stand-alone solution.